# Is there a way to check if the resource being updated/deleted exists in the validator? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, httpresponse

Currently, my controller delegates the **CRUD** operations to a **CRUDService**.

When for example, I need to update a resource, this request pass through the validator first, and then to the **CRUDService**. If this one finds that the resource does not exists, it will respond with 404.

Here's the snippet that performs this operation:

```
public function update($id, Request $input)
    {
        if ($this->notFound($id)) {
            return $this->response->notFound();
        }

        $input = $this->converter->convert($input);
        $this->model->where("id", $id)->update($input);

        return $this->response->updated();
    }


private function notFound($id)
    {
        return !count($this->model->find($id));
    }
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to perform this check inside the FormRequest class... Any suggestions?

Comment: after update this return updated id..

Comment: @D Coder Sorry?

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is. Check out the `exists` Laravel validation rule here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists

> ### exists:table,column
>
> The field under validation must exist on a given database table.
>
> #### Basic Usage Of Exists Rule
>
> 'state' => 'exists:states'

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. This Check assumes that you have a field to check against. But I don't have the id in the request array